# Utilizing symmetry in statics problem

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, statics, beam, deflection

I am given the structure below, and supposed to find the forces occuring in $A, F, E, D, C$ and $B$. The task hints of using symmetry, as several forces are equal in magnitude.

[image]

Supposedly, $A=B$, and $G=H$, where the image below depicts the top beam, and these forces.

[image]

My question is therefore *why* $A=B$ and $H=G$. I have asked other students/T.As., and they say it is obvious or intuitive, but can not really *explain*. Can anyone help?

Comment: The pairs A & B and H & G (as well as C & D and E & F for that matter) are symmetric. The load is evenly distributed and symmetric about both horizontal axes through the center of mass of the system. If you create a free body diagram and do a sum of forces and moments you should see that.

Comment: Imagine that another student was given the same problem, but the diagram given to them have the labels `A` and `G` interchanged with `B` and `H`. **1** would they arrive at the *same* answer ? **2** After seeing their diagram would you be able to tell if the labels were interchanged or just the viewing angle used to draw the diagram ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have no trouble identifying that the structure itself is symmetric, only how that automatically tells you that $A = B$ and $G = H$.

I'm going to take two approaches to this answer, one a bit blunter, the other a bit more visual.

---

### The blunt approach

One could argue that when the structure (including loading) is symmetric, the onus should be on you to give a reason why the reactions shouldn't be symmetric.

If the reactions aren't symmetric, then the internal stresses and deflection aren't symmetric. So why should a symmetric structure have asymmetric deflection? Why should its left span sag more (for example) than the right span?

Wouldn't that imply that the left span is more flexible or under greater load than the right span (which we know isn't the case, since it's symmetric)?

---

### The visual approach

Let's take a walk.

Initially, we are standing in a position such that we can see the structure exactly as shown in the problem statement, with A closer to us but slightly to our left and B in the distance, slightly to our right.

We then walk forwards and a bit to our right until we are exactly between the E and C supports and then we look at the rest of the structure. What we'll see is precisely what you drew: a horizontal beam that starts at A to our left, passes through G, then H, and ends at B. All those points have a 2-meter spacing between them, and the entire beam is under a distributed load $w$.<sup>1</sup>

[image]

Let's then say we sit down and work out all the reactions somehow. Now let's imagine that you get that $A \neq B$ and $G \neq H$. Specifically, let's say we get that $A > B$ and $G > H$. Or, put another way, we get that (left and right defined from our current position between C and E):

$$\begin{align}
\text{left-most reaction (A)} &> \text{right-most reaction (B)} \\
\text{left-inner reaction (G)} &> \text{right-inner reaction (H)}
\end{align}$$

We haven't thought about symmetry yet, so we just accept that result as correct and move on.

Now we stand up and walk around the entire structure until we are standing precisely between supports D and F, and we once again look at the rest of the structure. This time we see a horizontal beam that starts at B to our left, passes through H, then G, and ends at A. All those points have a 2-meter spacing between them, and the entire beam is under a distributed load $w$.

[image]

Now, do we need to sit down and calculate the results for this "new" beam? Of course not. It's obviously the same beam we calculated before, just from a different perspective.

But still, let's say we did go through the trouble of redoing our calculations. Assuming we did everything exactly the same way as the first time, we'd once again get that:

$$\begin{align}
\text{left-most reaction} &> \text{right-most reaction} \\
\text{left-inner reaction} &> \text{right-inner reaction}
\end{align}$$

But this time that means that $B > A$ and $H > G$...

So when we looked at the beam from one perspective (between C and E) we get a different result than we got from another (between D and F). That obviously makes no physical sense: the beam's true reactions don't care about where we are standing when we calculate them.

So we know that our result is incorrect. And in fact, we can ask ourselves: what's the only result that's independent of where we're standing? One where $A = B$ and $G = H$.<sup>2</sup>

This thought experiment only works when the beam is symmetrical. After all, when the beam is symmetrical, the change in perspective is simply an inversion of the labels. Why should beam A-G-H-B have different results than those from B-H-G-A?

If it isn't symmetric (say, if the spans are actually 1 m (A to G), 3 m (G to H) and 2 m (H to B), then our calculation standing between C and E will give us that:

$$\begin{align}
\text{left-most reaction (A)} &< \text{right-most reaction (B)} \\
\text{left-inner reaction (G)} &< \text{right-inner reaction (H)}
\end{align}$$

and the result standing between D and F will be consistent:

$$\begin{align}
\text{left-most reaction (B)} &> \text{right-most reaction (A)} \\
\text{left-inner reaction (H)} &> \text{right-inner reaction (G)}
\end{align}$$

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>In the diagrams below, G and H should actually be springs; they've been marked as rigid supports to keep thing simple and because this is irrelevant to the question at hand.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Obviously one where all reactions are equal would also be independent of where we're standing but would fail to satisfy the standard equilibrium equations.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

For the system shown, intuitively we can cut the beam at halfway between the support points G & H, so the left half is a mirror image of the right half regarding geometry, loading, support reactions, and member internal forces, so we can analyze half of the structure to obtain the same results. However, the trick is what type of support needs to be assigned to the joint at the cut.

From the full structure, it is expected that there is a positive (smiley) moment at the mid-point of the interior span, so we need to keep the joint fixed to draw moment to the joint, however, by doing so the resulting moment won't be correct (which will be negative), so we realize, in order to get the correct result, we need to modify the joint support specification.

Now, by examining the expected deflection of the full structure at the same location of the cut, we know the joint must be able to move freely in the vertical direction to allow deflection to occur, so we need to remove the restrain in the Y direction. Note, by releasing the vertical support at the cut, the moment curve is corrected as well.

The graph below shows the analyses results of the reduced model, which has the rightmost support fixed with Y fixity released, and the full structure.

[image]

**General Procedures:**

1. Cut the structure at a point that will result in one side structure is the mirror image of the other.
2. Inspect the moment and deflection curves on the whole structure at the cut location to determine the support type to be specified to the joint of the cut. Consider partial release of support fixity if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To determine if the system is symmetric or not, always first find the center point of the complete structure. Then imagine many planes at the center point to check if the system is symmetric or not about that plane. We usually begin with XY, XZ and YZ planes.

Generally, symmetry means that the structure is symmetric about any of the planes, the loads are symmetric about that plane, the connections are symmetric about that plane and supports are symmetric about that plane. If any of these criterias are not satisfied, then the system is not symmetric and you cannot make use of the simplified symmetric behavior.

Symmetry simply means mirror of one half. If you are conducting a Finite Element analysis and want to make use of symmetry, then we usually enter some constraints at the faces which are cut at the plane of symmetry. These constraints are that:

i) The face (where the structure is cut at the plane of symmetry) cannot translate normal to its direction.

ii) The face (where the structure is cut at the plane of symmetry) cannot rotate about the other two orthagonal directions.

Think about these two constraints to model symmetry and you will understand how it can mimic the symmetric behavior. If you can also somehow apply these constraints onto your analytical static model, then you are good to solve.